# How do scientists study liquid tungsten?

Tags: melting-point

Inspired by this What If article: https://what-if.xkcd.com/50/

In the above article, Randall Munroe mentions that liquid tungsten is difficult to study because of its extremely high melting point. Because of this property, containers for the tungsten tend to melt before the metal itself. This might be a fairly elementary question, but given this difficulty, what methods do modern chemists use to study it, or other materials with extreme melting points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use electristatic or electromagnetic forces to hold the liquud in place.  [This abstract](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/htj.20101) refers to a "non-contact method" and an "electrostatic levitate", which us enough to reveal the basic strategy.  Unfortunately the article is behind a paywall, so you have to put up to get details on the good stuff.

Industrially, metals like tungsten are not processed as liquids.  They are ... see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powder_metallurgy).